# Hyperledger fabric peer keep on creating chaincode docker images for pervious chaincode versions

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a hyperledger fabric network v2.4.4 running on kubernetes. The chaincode is running in a docker-in-docker pod. Whenever pod restart, the peer keep on creating docker images for old versions of chaincode. When I execute `docker images`, there are nearly 80 docker images for old chaincode versions as shown in the logs:

```
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_105-936069cbdf0163cbdce749e934c5cc04f384730851111269c4d3b7e1e21de233-d1ee8eaa58c5dcc654d456bbd4924cd4c250855383555b6eb48a40a0708b514f   latest    909eb887231c   14 hours ago   374MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_104-c22518cbcdaddda02586cce22c2dfc4451655791f94b69dfbc7042e77b65ef7f-c2bdab17d43e5acb46fe9bb72b88e1f32a56f5e3a4046ba23afb93c8a2fc2514   latest    bafee457583f   14 hours ago   374MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_103-3a98e22e19b2323280cfc592aeb3485a4c61184b9d7ee8e03b509ca35679fa72-6a736daf1a566b8f696ae229c814406f694a785b00e4013787f69d284c8698af   latest    e23c81ddc011   14 hours ago   374MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_102-42f758c013a5e24d6fa672bfb736fed32440cf20b73d0f15a4cb2877fdd93718-a3f847137277712e37fdc61ba31f4387098fc5347a028b551636013bce194d03   latest    5149210d8af1   14 hours ago   374MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_101-aa5f8c94fede2379982de5862ae1baf0648192f894894ae5c454ebe454073112-576ea12f03a9dfa4c58df27603f6d13b59e87edd005415d90112937bcbd23f44   latest    dc38389cc596   14 hours ago   374MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_100-64429fc37d25efdcf2518823fe1235fe478d3b91270ceed919efd55c1a62f0df-ad60d1cdfe0e3a6a3d96c27c93c06f32c78a2e2f20485c3fb30ba8f49604b239   latest    2b3f5e015955   14 hours ago   374MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_10-9f82c0de800c863b2d8cf50262f8e9ad709f406c847f77a8261400cef64dbfcb-0226f9a53b4e47fe46c7d732f0ce77e344778e3bd93a5a9c472ea1f9746affdd    latest    1976afc3ba18   14 hours ago   376MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_1-c98d464c9dd0e9db03c2e213e2f1ef109a5d3e83ea21adbe88d96b7178f156c0-d8ea0bd5d87647fcf3a97c7af5fece5de4d99edf7964de7cd5fe9ce809e1cb28     latest    af153893f6ce   14 hours ago   376MB
dev-peer0.org1.com-assets_1-4f730c5825c60f1d3cc4b04e8e668db9992c0413b54c10bca76066a3f87cf4e3-2ba27ea16a5ad099a4e32deaa00982c266fd05e993370d104669d96b86904d65     latest    1a556e11cc87   14 hours ago   376MB
hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv                                                                                                                                        2.4       31959bcd1525   2 months ago   341MB
```

Is there anyway to stop this or at least restrict the number of old chaincode containers a peer can create?

Comment: Is running chaincode as an external service an option?

Comment: We do not run chaincode as an external service as we want it to be automated and managed by peer only

Comment: If the peer is needlessly building images of chaincode that are not active on a channel, then I would say that is a bug. Can you confirm via peer logs that that is actually what is happening ? If so I would suggest raising a github issue. On a side note, DinD is not a good solution to the removal of docker from K8s, you should use an external builder if you don't want to use external chaincode. See https://github.com/hyperledgendary/fabric-builder-k8s for one approach